# Does buying things from other peoples towns have any negative impact on them or other members of your guild?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-series, the-elder-scrolls-blades

When you're in a "guild" you can visit other peoples towns and buy things from their shops, does this prevent them, or other people in your guild from buying those same items?

Answer (score 1):

> Players can’t sell or craft items in another player’s Town, but they can check in with the local Merchant to see what wares they have on sale. Don’t worry about players buying up everything in your Town during their stay, as Merchants stock a unique inventory for every visiting player!

[from the Bethesda announcement](https://elderscrolls.bethesda.net/en/article/6FHaMtCCylGToQ0Moh1Neq/the-elder-scrolls-blades-getting-the-most-from-guilds)